# Got socket error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: dart, flutter

Whenever i try to create a new project in flutter through git bash or command prompt, i keep on getting this error `Got socket error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.` I have upgraded the flutter sdk to the latest version but still the same problem. Please how do i solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm having the same problem on my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 OS.

Comment: i didn't solve it but the issue is gone with the stable release

Comment: Do you need a proxy configuration to access public internet? https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall

Answer (score 9):

I would advice anyone that might still be having this problem to TRY the following simply steps:

1. open environment variable settings
2. create a new variable with the name: PUB_HOSTED_URL and its value: https://pub.flutter-io.cn
3. create a new variable with the name: FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL and its value: https://storage.flutter-io.cn

This did it for me. After spending weeks tryna figure it out. Would love to save someone the headache i went through.

Comment: sorry it doesnt work. worked for me at the time. i am guessing with flutter updates there might have been some changes that might prevent it from being a solution. Take into account the working environment. I use windows 10 with flutter 1.7.8+ hotfix (at the time). You might want to look into solution for your specific version

Comment: this works for me. though I think it is a temporary solution. a permanent solution would have to deal with firewall and proxies allowing the default url

Comment: @leonard kakande you're probably right. However, I've been using this for as long as I can remember and didn't even think about it. When you do get a solution that's universal do share.

Answer (score 6):

#### On Linux, this worked for me and for many other people... It should work for you too.

```sh
export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn
export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn
```

#### On windows, you should create an environment variable with:

```
name: PUB_HOSTED_URL
 
value: https://pub.flutter-io.cn

name: FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL

value: https://storage.flutter-io.cn
```

Answer (score 4):

I have both issues. With:

1. Corporate firewall. Look [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall) for solution
2. Env variables (Win system env vars). Create two of them:

   - **name**: PUB_HOSTED_URL; **value**: https://pub.flutter-io.cn
   - **name**: FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL; **value**: https://storage.flutter-io.cn

Answer (score 1):

Spent 2 hours on it myself, in addition to the previous settings, check your antivirus, mine automatically blocked flutter, so disable your antivirus completely it and then try running again, hope this helps someone.

Comment: Using AVG here, I disabled web-shield and it worked...Not sure about why is it blocked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Using a VPN for access to the internet did the trick for me.

Comment: Yeah. Seems that the internet provider was blocking it

Answer (score 0):

I have found that resetting your wifi router works. It's happened to me twice and it worked after I reset my router.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!. its an **Admin Access Issue**.

I solved it by running the command `flutter pub get` in an **Administrator CMD terminal**.

*PS. I guess running VScode as an Admin would have also solved the issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your system. it worked for me. Restarting the system did reset the firewall setting and the request worked without changing the pub host url.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).