# How can i fix this error in Android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

please I was trying to run this but it returns an error

```
Got socket error trying to find package flutter_lints at [https://pub.dev](https://pub.dev).
pub get failed
command: "C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\Anselem\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 69
```

> i was trying to run ***flutter pub get***

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please i have been trying to run the flutter pub get but it throws back that error

Comment: Try the solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158282/got-socket-error-trying-to-find-package-cupertino-icons-at-https-pub-dartlang